# Write form inputs to text file using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, fopen, fwrite

What I am trying to do is to write the inputs from the form, on submit, in a separate text file. Please mind that the form cannot be altered with.

Question is, how to save the input in a separate TXT file?
This is the form:

```
<form method="post">
<textarea id="name"></textarea>
<textarea id="message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

This is how I try to do it:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
  $name = $_POST['#name'];
  $message = $_POST['#message'];
  $text = $name . "," . $message . "\n";
  $fp = fopen('questions.txt', 'a+');

    if(fwrite($fp, $text))  {
//  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
//  error_reporting(E_ALL);
        echo 'Thank you!';
    }
fclose ($fp);    
} ?>
```

Please mind that I have read many solutions here, all forms having the inputs with names (ie `name='message'`). Unfortunately, my form cannot be altered with, that's why I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to use `$name=$_POST['#name']` hoping the input ID will be used (notice the #).

Can I save the inputs to a text file, without modifying the form?
The file questions.txt exists and it is writable 777.

Thank you.

Comment: forgot to mention that uncommenting the error lines doesn't show any PHP errors. The form is submitted, but the details not written to the file, which is empty.

Comment: Form elements must have a name property in order to be valid and readable by PHP. IDs are not a suitable substitute

Comment: Put the error lines at the top of your file, right after the `<?php` line.  You'll probably get warnings about undefined variables / array elements.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Your_first_form#sending_form_data_to_your_web_server : _"We provide a name attribute for each form control. The names are important on both the client- and server-side; they tell the browser which name to give each piece of data and, on the server side, they let the server handle each piece of data by name. The form data is sent to the server as name/value pairs."_. You don't have any names in your form fields. There's also https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php.This is fairly basic knowledge if you've followed any tutorials really

Comment: `Unfortunately, my form cannot be altered`...why on earth not? That makes no sense. The form will never send anything to the server without them, regardless of anything you change in the PHP. The data never reaches PHP.

Comment: @adyson it is a WP contact plugin, and for some reason the devs decided to encrypt it, so its files (form) cannot be altered with. I can however append any code in the footer (the 'how I try to do it'), and I hope by doing this there's a method to also catch the form inputs.

Comment: You can't encrypt html. It has to be sent to the browser in a parseable format. They've perhaps made it hard for humans to read, or hard to see how it generates it, but ultimately the output would be some comprehensible html tags. Anyway it makes zero sense that they would build a form which can't be submitted. I'd be sending in a support request if that's the case...but then surely they must have tested it, it would be pretty obvious if that part was failing.

Comment: @adyson for the love of God, the form is generated (as I can see it in the page source) by the encrypted php (wp plugin) files. Cannot change those files, hence my struggle. Everything clear now?

Comment: You can't encrypt PHP files either - it has to be delivered as source code, otherwise the PHP interpreter can't execute it. It could be obfuscated perhaps...and granted that might make it very difficult to alter it, but it certainly isn't technically impossible, with sufficient effort. But if they made the code generate a form you can't submit, and you can't realistically figure out how to alter the code, then you need to contact the plugin maintainer and ask them to fix it. Because otherwise it seems like the plugin is basically useless.

Comment: P.S. If it's a plugin though, surely the makers already wrote some backend code which handles the form submission?? (maybe they submit it from the browser using AJAX, hence why it doesn't need name attributes...just a guess?). Or is it literally just something which makes a HTML form, and you have to deal with the rest yourself?

Comment: @adyson ioncube

Comment: Ah a commercial extension. Its effectively a completely different runtime

Answer (score 1):

There's a catalog of issues here.

> that's why I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to use $name=$_POST['#name'] hoping the input ID will be used (notice the #).

It would be really trivial to check this by look at the data your browser is sending using the provided web developer tools or by pointing the form at (for example):

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
</pre>
```

At least in Firefox, the browser does not send ANY data back to the server apart from the submit button. If you can't rewrite the HTML page with the form (or add Javascript) then this will never work.

Leaving that aside for now....

> Can I save the inputs to a text file

Yes, but this is a bad idea. There are multiple reasons we use databases for storing data.

> it is writable 777

That is always a bad idea. So is allowing PHP to write to files inside your web root.

Comment: I can add Javascript. As explained above, it is a WP contact plugin that is encrypted, so the files/form cannot be changed. I don't care much about security, I only want an extra log that proves someone contacted me, hence the extra 777 file. I thought this to be the easiest approach, but I'm starting to doubt. The plugin itself keeps the logs, the external file would be some kind of backup to those messages.  PS why mentioning javascript, is there a way to do it using js?